# I am trying to modify and make permanent changes in the SAS data set, but I am not able to do so

Tags: sas, dataset, proc, datastep, sas-dis

I want to make permanent changes is the variable name Fclass and label Date as Departure date.
i have used the modify statement along with rename but I am getting error when I am running the program.

```
proc datasets library= ia;
modify passngrs;
rename FClass= First Class;
label Date='Departure date';
format Date date9.;
run;
```

Comment: "rename FClass= First Class;" -> "First Class" does not look like a valid SAS column name.

Comment: Why are you just assigning a label to DATE but trying to rename FCLASS?  The easiest fix is to remove the space from the new name.  `rename fclass=FirstClass;`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do any of these:

- Rename to a variable name that does not contain a space
  `rename FCLASS = FirstClass;`
- Rename to a trickier name by using session options and a name literal
  `options validvarname=any;
  proc ...;
  ...;
  rename FCLASS = 'First Class'N;`
- Use a label for `FCLASS` instead of renaming it
  `label FCLASS = 'First Class';`